Replacing depricated @GenericGenerator to @IdGeneratorType generating negative sequences and throwing DuplicateKeyException
Using spring-boot 3.3.0. Tried replace @GenericGenerator to @IdGeneratorType.
Before deprication used abstract entity with generic generator for all entities.
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @GenericGenerator(name = CustomSequenceGenerator.NAME,
            strategy = CustomSequenceGenerator.STR_NAME,
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10")
            }
    )

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = CustomSequenceGenerator.NAME)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    ...
}

Created sequence generator:
@IdGeneratorType(CustomSequenceGenerator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SequenceGenerated {

    int startWith() default 1;
    int incrementBy() default 50;
    Class<? extends Optimizer> optimizer() default HiLoOptimizer.class;

}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerated()
    @GeneratedValue(generator = CustomSequenceGenerator.NAME)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    ...
}

Sequence name generating inside CustomSequenceGenerator.
Now i getting negative numbers in ID when inserting 10-20 rows.
If i inserting 100+ rows getting : org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.
What did i miss?

Hi, can you share more details about CustomSequenceGenerator class? May the problems that you described be originated from bad concurrency management?

Try starting with 50 instead of at 1?
